# Docusign api Folders: list subfolders not appearing

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to get all template folders including subfolders from the API. I attempted to use the folders:list api method https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/list/ setting the include parameter to "template_folders" which brings back the templates folder and the first level of user folders including the "hasSubFolders" boolean but I do not get a list of subfolders. Is there a way to get the whole hierarchy from the API? The documentation seems to indicate the whole list of folders and subfolders should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From postman or just calling raw APIs you need to do this:

```
/folders?user_filter=owned_by_me&include=envelope_folders,template_folders,shared_template_folders&sub_folder_depth=-1
```

I think the key is the `sub_folder_depth=-1` which I assume -1 means to go as deep as needed.